# JPA/Criteria - Select (or multiselect) on SetAttribute

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, setattribute

I am getting really frustrated trying to use JPA criterias (I am using Hibernate implementation).. I want to make a query where the select is on a Set of objects, but I can't make it work..

Here is my code:

```
public List<Object> findAllTypeGroupes(){
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery =  criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object.class);

    /* FROM */
    Root<Contact> contactRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Contact.class);
    /* SELECT */
    criteriaQuery.select( contactRoot.get( Contact_.groupes ) );

    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}

@StaticMetamodel(Contact.class)
public abstract class Contact_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Contact, Integer> contactId;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<Contact, TypeGroupe> groupes;
}
```

If I try to make a select on "Contact_.groupes", where "groupes" is a set (c.f. metamodel: "SetAttribute"), I was expecting to get a List>, but I am actually getting a flatten list List... Hibernate is actually generating one single SQL query, when I was expecting to get a query for each item/set of my List....

But what I originally wanted was to make a query with a multiselect to get couple of fields, one of them beeing my Set.. If I try to make a multiselect with my "Contact_.groupes" and for instance "Contact.contactId" like here:

```
public List<Object[]> findAllWrapperByCriteria(ContactCriteria criteria){
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);

    /* FROM */
    Root<Contact> contactRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Contact.class);

    criteriaQuery.multiselect( contactRoot.get( Contact_.contactId ), contactRoot.get( Contact_.groupes ) );


    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```

Things are obviously not working eather and I am getting an exception this time, because Hibernate generated me a bad SQL Query:

```
select contact0_.CONTACT_ID as col_0_0_, . as col_1_0_, typegroupe2_.TYPE_GROUPE_ID as TYPE1_6_, typegroupe2_.LIBELLE as LIBELLE6_, typegroupe2_.MUT_TS as MUT3_6_, typegroupe2_.MUT_USER as MUT4_6_, typegroupe2_.REMARQUE as REMARQUE6_, typegroupe2_.VISIBLE as VISIBLE6_ from CONTACT contact0_ inner join CONTACT_GROUPE groupes1_ on contact0_.CONTACT_ID=groupes1_.CONTACT_ID inner join TYPE_GROUPE typegroupe2_ on groupes1_.GROUPE_TYPE_GROUPE_ID=typegroupe2_.TYPE_GROUPE_ID
```

As you can see just after the first coma: ". as col_1_0_" which isn't a valid SQL query..

So I really don't know how to do what I want.. On my object Contact, all fields are eager, because when I load a contact I close the transaction and thus the object get detached and won't allow me to get data lazy loaded. But I have a "search screen" where I am displaying a subset of all contacts fields.. So in order to dramatically increase perforances, I was willing to make a specific query for this part and load only what I need instead of a "SELECT * FROM Contact"...

Does somebody have any idea of what is going on and how to solve my problem ?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of trouble. Is using JPA the only option for you?

Comment: The purpose of the query is not clear to me. Do you want to retrieve the groups of a given contact? Is that what you are trying to do? Otherwise, could you please state what is the purpose of you query?

Comment: @Lukas Eder: Yes, JPA is a requirement in my project.. @Edalorzo: Well, not really, I want to retrieve the groups of all contacts as well as couple of other fields, like the contacts' id, first name and last name, for instance. So basically for each contact I want its id, first name, last name and groups (where groups is a set).. I am thus expecting a List<Object[]> as result, where Object[0] = id (Integer), Object[1] = first name (String), Object[2] = las name (String) and Object[3] = groups (Set<TypeGroupe>)